# Normal to the reflecting plane

Tags: linear-algebra

> $$A=\frac{1}{9}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> -1 & 8 & 4 \\
>  -4& -4 & 7 \\
>  -8& 1 & -4 \end{array} \right) $$
>
> Find the normal to the reflecting plane and costruct an orthonormal basis $\{\hat{e}_1,\hat{e}_2,\hat{e}_3\}$ including the normal to the reflecting plane $\hat{e}_3=\hat{n}$ and $\hat{e}_1=\left(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)$.

I am not sure how to go about solving this problem.

We have that the eigenvalue is $\lambda=-1$ and the corresponding eigenvector is $v_1=(1/2,-1,1)$, but how can I construct an orthonormal basis $\{\hat{e}_1,\hat{e}_2,\hat{e}_3\}$ including the normal to the reflecting plane $\hat{e}_3=\hat{n}$ and $\hat{e}_1=\left(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)$?

We have that the matrix $A$ is an orthogonal matrix and that it is a reflection matrix since the determinant is $-1$. Do I apply the cross product to find the normal to the reflection plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the geometry of the situation: if $\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}\\n$ is normal (perpendicular) to the reflecting plane, then it will be reflected "straight backwards", that is,
$$A\\n=-\\n\ .$$
This means that $\\n$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $-1$.  If you know how to find eigenvectors, you should now be able to finish the problem.

Comment: We have that $\lambda=-1$ and the corresponding eigenvector is $v_1=(1/2,-1,1)$. But how can I construct an orthonormal basis $\{\hat{e}_1,\hat{e}_2,\hat{e}_3\}$ including the normal to the reflecting plane $\hat{e}_3=\hat{n}$ and $\hat{e}_1=\left(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)$?

Comment: So, then you *can* use the cross product: $\hat{\bf e}_2=\hat{\bf e}_3\times\hat{\bf e}_1$.  Alternatively, you need two vectors satisfying $\frac{1}{2}x-y+z=0$: by trial and error $(0,1,1)$ will do, then take $(a,1,-1)$, which will be perpendicular to $(0,1,1)$, and will satisfy the equation if you choose a suitable $a$.  Then reduce both of these to unit length.

Answer (score 0):

Find the eigenvalues of $A$ and $2$ independent eigenvectors
$v_{1},v_{2}$ then $A$ reflects around $$W:=sp\{v_{1},v_{2}\}$$ now
use the fact that 
$$
V=W\oplus W^{\perp}
$$

for $V=\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and complete $W$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$
with $w_{3}\in W^{\perp}$.

If you want a perpendicular vector with norm of $1$ then you can
take $\frac{w_{3}}{||w_{3}||}$

Comment: I am bit confused on your notation. What does $V=W\oplus W^{\perp}$ mean and $w_3$?

Comment: @robben $W^{\perp}$ designates those vectors which are orthogonal to $W$ (i.e., the vectors $w'$ for which $w\cdot w'=0\forall w\in W$).  $w_3$ represents an arbitrary member of $W^{\perp}$; you can show that they're all scalar multiples of each other (why?).